# Connection timeout solving

Tags: curl, networking, soap, firewall, iptables

I have a private ip server with soap service:
http://172.28.93.206:8081/SMSD_SOAP1/RMIUniversalConnectorService?WSDL
I can access it from local browser, it has basic auth, and all works properly.
But my server which is in a same network, can't reach this soap service.
I tried curl with basic auth params, initializing soap class in php, file_get_contents in php - all of these tryings ends with connection timeout. Service's server side set correctly, 8081 port is open and as I said can be accessable via browser. How to fix issue on my side?
ps ping to 172.28.93.206 is correct from my server

Answer (score 2):

Try to figure out these things:

- if internet access is restricted by http proxy ? ( 'env | grep -i proxy' will be useful )
- runs curl with '--verbose' flag as well as dump http headers into stout via '-D -'
- last when run above curl request in parallel console run 'netstat -p tcp | grep 172.28.93.206' to see what's is going on in tcp/ip context

Hopefully, having this info will lead you to further guessing ...

Comment: 1. Outputs nothing. 2. -bash-4.2$ curl --verbose http://172.28.93.206:8081
* About to connect() to 172.28.93.206 port 8081 (#0)
*   Trying 172.28.93.206...
* Connection timed out
* Failed connect to 172.28.93.206:8081; Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 172.28.93.206:8081; Connection timed out
3. Outputs help instruction how to set command. Can you provide command for centos (7)?

Comment: Well I am wonder if 8081 port is reachable , what does 'telnet 172.28.93.206 8081' say ?

Comment: Use nestat to see what happening with tcp connections between your local host and 172.28.93.206 , you should run netstat at parallel console while requesting URL with curl or telnet . Another thing if host reachable when requested from some else server ? What ping says ? ( be aware that  ping won't help you unless you have icpm enabled at your network )